# Memoir: generic hook is deprecated

Tags: memoir, hooks

Since a couple of months, I get the following warnings when using the `memoir` class.

```
Generic hook 'package/before/framed' is deprecated.
Generic hook 'package/before/float' is deprecated.
```

Is this problematic? I there a proper way to fix these warnings?

In combination with the `hyperref` package, the following two warnings appear as well (from the `memhfixc` package).

```
Generic hook 'package/after/nameref' is deprecated.
Generic hook 'package/after/hypcap' is deprecated.
```

Comment: it's fixed in the develpment sources I believe but in any case you can ignore the warning, the old name still works so the class is working as intended.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay, thanks for the quick respone. Any chance the fix will be published soon?

Comment: ask Daleif :-) ....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That indeed answers my question. Thanks. I will mark this as a duplicate.